# Why the color doesn't change when the button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs

Not sure why this is not working, when i click the buttons nothing changes?

I'm trying to create a login/signin page in ReactJs

Imports on page:

```html
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Component:

```js
import React from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
function Body() {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("pink");
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.background = color;
  }, [color]);

  function ChangeColor() {
    setColor("red");
  }
  return (
    <div className="Body">
      <h3>Already have an account? </h3>
      <Button content="Sign In" onClick={() => ChangeColor()} />
      <h3>Don't have an account? </h3>
      <Button content="Sign Up" onClick={() => ChangeColor()} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Body;
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: If you want to access DOM elements in React, use useRef hook.

In your case, if you want to change the style of the body, you should use <div style: backgroundColor: color> ... </dv>

Comment: Please also show the Button component. Is the onClick listener also passed down to the actual DOM element, such as <a> or <button>, that is used there?

Comment: I believe the problem is inside your `Button` component, can you share the code?

Comment: import React from 'react'

function Button({content}) {
    
    return (
        <button>{content}</button>
    )
}

export default Button
@Eduard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add onclick event to your Button component to which you pass the handler from the props.

```
import React from "react";

function Button({ content, onClick /* <- Here */ }) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{content}</button>;
}                         // ^ HERE 

export default Button;
```